# Make a unique list of values from a particular key existing anywhere in a deep array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, array-unique, array-key

I have an array that consists of an undetermined number of arrays, recursively (n levels deep). Each array might contain a `name` key. I want to create a unique list of those values.

**Example**

Suppose the array is:

```
$bigArray = array(
    'name'=>'one', 
    'something'=>array(
        'name'=>'two', 
        'subthing'=>array('name'=>'three')
    ), 
    'anotherthing'=>array('name'=>'one')
);
```

The expected result would be:

```
$uniques = array('one', 'two', 'three') // All the 'name' keys values and without duplicates.
```

Here's a [fiddle of my attempt](http://ideone.com/0Jw8ys).

My approach was using `array_walk_recursive` passing a `$uniques` array as reference, and allowing the function to update that value:

```
$uniques = array();

function singleOut($item, $key, &$uniques) {
    if ($key == 'name' && !in_array($itm,$uniques,true) )
        $uniques[] = $item;
}

array_walk_recursive($bigArray, 'singleOut', $uniques);
```

However, it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use also `array_unique` on this one too. Example:

```
$uniques = array();
array_walk_recursive($bigArray, function($val, $key) use (&$uniques){
    if($key == 'name') {
        $uniques[] = $val;
    }
});

$uniques = array_unique($uniques); // unique values
```

Comment: For the scope of this question, a loose comparison is just fine.  However, visit this link to see the potential unexpected outcomes (thanks to PHP's type juggling) when using loose comparisons on keys that _may_ be `0`.  [Type juggling while making loose comparison yields unwanted result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426990/type-juggling-while-making-loose-comparison-yields-unwanted-result)]

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle was nearly spot on - the problem was, that the user parameter is given by-reference only within same levels of recursion. You need to use indirection with a reference:

```
$bigArray = array(
    'name'=>'one', 
    'something'=>array(
        'name'=>'two', 
        'subthing'=>array('name'=>'three')
    ), 
    'anotherthing'=>array('name'=>'one')
);

function singleOut($item, $key, $indirect) {
    $uniques=&$indirect[0];
    if ($key == 'name' && !in_array($item,$uniques,true) ) $uniques[] = $item;

}

$uniques = array();
$indirect = array(&$uniques);
array_walk_recursive($bigArray, 'singleOut', $indirect);
print_r($uniques);
```

**Edit:**

Fiddle is [here](http://ideone.com/nO7FL0)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid doing an `in_array()` check inside of `array_walk_recursive()`, you can store `name` values as keys in the output array.  This will effectively eliminate duplicates by overwriting previous identical keys.  When `array_walk_recursive()` is finished, you can use `array_keys()` to move the data from keys to values.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f9d579d406bb617981cf825c45975c28e60917f))

```
$bigArray=[
    'name'=>'one', 
    'something'=>[
        'name'=>'two', 
        'subthing'=>['name'=>'three']
    ], 
    'anotherthing'=>['name'=>'one']
];
array_walk_recursive($bigArray,function($v,$k)use(&$uniques){
    if($k==='name')
        $uniques[$v]='';
});
var_export(array_keys($uniques));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'one',
  1 => 'two',
  2 => 'three',
)
```

Because `array_unique()` can be slow in some cases, using `array_keys()` should generally perform faster.  That said, if micro-optimization is a concern then you should do benchmark testing using your actual data and your specific environment and select the best method for your project.

As I mentioned in a comment under Ghost's answer, it is a good habit to make `===` strict comparisons on keys in your multi-dimensional array because if you are looking for a string, but encounter a `0` key, then PHP's type juggling "feature" will provide unexpected results.

Here is a page where I discuss and demonstrate this behavior: [Type juggling while making loose comparison yields unwanted result](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f9d579d406bb617981cf825c45975c28e60917f)