# Multidimensional array loop to get value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of multiple arrays all with different levels. What im trying to do is loop though the array by key, and it will go through each level getting the values for those keys. myArray looks something like this

```
Array ( [0] => 
  Array ( [Date] => 2011-15-22 
          [Color] => blue
          [Status] => Fresh 
        [1] => 
  Array ( [Date] => 1999-08-04 
          [Color] => green
          [Status] => Rotten) )
```

I have tried

```
foreach($myArray as $row){
  foreach($row["Date"] as $k){
     echo $k
    } 
 }
```

I am getting an

```
Notice: Undefined index: Date
```

and

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: Are you *only* getting these errors ? Are you certain the array structure is exactly the same for all elements (figuring you have a lot more than 2 items)

Comment: `$row["Date"]` is a string, `foreach` doesn't complain for nothing.

Comment: just do `echo $row["Date"]` - no need for the nested foreach if you just want the date.

Comment: @Calimero Yes structure is same for all arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a unique list of values from a particular key existing anywhere in a deep array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634515/make-a-unique-list-of-values-from-a-particular-key-existing-anywhere-in-a-deep-a)  ... of course, you can omit the final step of removing duplicates if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply with `array_walk_recursive` function:

```
$arr = [
    [ 'Date' => '2011-15-22', 'Color' => 'blue', 'Status' => 'Fresh' ],
    [ 'Date' => '1999-08-04', 'Color' => 'green', 'Status' => 'Rotten' ]
];

array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k){
    if ($k == 'Date') echo $v . PHP_EOL;
});
```

The output:

```
2011-15-22
1999-08-04
```

Answer (score 1):

On your foreach, you should specify the key and value so you can access both:

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' is '. gettype ($value).'<br>';
    if (is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $subKey => $subValue){
            echo $subkey . ' => ' . $subValue . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can access and print all values without losing the structure

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Because `$row["Date"]` is string

[`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) -  foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.

> Notice: Undefined index: Date

Probably your array may not have element with key `Date` somewhere (your array structure probably different, as iteration takes place), so you are getting this message, use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to or [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to validate, depending on the purpose.

Please note `isset != array_key_exists`

```
$a = array('key1' => 'test1', 'key2' => null);
isset($a['key2']);             // false
array_key_exists('key2', $a);  // true
```

There is another important difference. `isset` doesn't complain when `$a` does not exist, while `array_key_exists` does.

Comment: I got rid of the second foreach but the i am getting the undefined index error. Date is a string how can i fix this error

Comment: Printing the result of the foreach after adding an if isset statment returns nothing. But if i dynamically return myArray[0]["Date"] it will return content

Comment: isset or array_key_exists is for validation if required, if your array is same as above this `foreach($myArray as $row){ echo $row['Date']; }` should work

Comment: My array structure is as posted above but i am still getting undefined index: Date error

Answer (score 0):

As axiac states in the comments, `$row["Date"]`is a String and therefore not iterable. You probably just want this:

```
foreach($myArray as $row){
  foreach($row as $k){
     echo $k
    } 
 }
```

The Notice `Undefined index: Date` also describes what is going wrong - you are accessing the index without checking if it exists. It does look like that your data structure is not always the same. In this case you should always check the existence with the [isset](http://php.net/isset) function:

```
if (isset($row["Date"])) {
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: How can i use the isset on date. Date is returning as a string.

Comment: `isset` just does one thing: It tells you if a variable is `null` (which every variable is by default) or not. It does not matter what you pass in there.

Comment: Printing the result of the foreach after adding an if isset statment returns nothing. But if i dynamically return myArray[0]["Date"] it will return content

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need this:

```
foreach($myArray as $row){
  echo $row["Date"]; 
 }
```

or

```
foreach($myArray as $row){
  $k= $row["Date"]; 
  //do stuff...
 }
```

or

```
foreach($myArray as $row){
  $k[]= $row["Date"]; 
 }
// do stuff with $k[] array.
```

Comment: I am getting an undefined index error for Date. Is there something i am missing. Date is a string

Comment: @jumpman8947 You shouldn't get that warning if the structure of all arrays is the same as you showed.